# Why would Z/P cancellation with real part > 0 between the plant and the controller make the system unstable?

Tags: control-system, theory

[image]

Can someone help me verify the claim if there is a zero pole cancellation with real part > 0 between controller Gc and plant Gp, then the system is not stable?

I can't find any literature that confirms or denies this claim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were possible to place a zero at EXACTLY the same location as a right half plane pole then the pole would be cancelled. However, exact placement is not achievable practically. The result is a pole and zero very close together on the positive real axis of the s-plane. Consequently, the root locus will have a branch on the positive real axis, going from the pole to the zero, which will give an unstable closed-loop. The zero, essentially, traps the pole in the right half plane.

If, instead, the zero were placed at an appropriate position on the real NEGATIVE axis, the root locus would have the capacity of moving the unstable pole into the left half plane and hence provide a stable closed loop.

Consider the very simple case of an open-loop with a single pole at s=1, i.e. an OLTF:

G(s) = 1/(s-1)

Placing a zero at, say, s=0.9 would give an OLTF:

G(s)=(s-0.9)/(s-1) and a CLTF = (s-0.9)/(2s-1.9), which is unstable.

However, placing a zero at s=-2 would give an OLTF:

G(s)=(s+2)/(s-1) and a CLTF = (s+2)/(2s+1) which has a stable closed-loop pole; ie, the unstable open loop pole at s=1 has been dragged into the left-hand plane by the zero, and now lies at s=-0.5

Comment: Sounds plausible...if the plant has a pole at s = 2, then theoretically a controller can be designed which has a zero at s = 2...but this is not practically achievable. Can you back up this with some references? much thanks

Comment: I don't have a suitable reference at the moment, but if I built an op-amp circuit to place a zero at a given position, normal component tolerances, not to mention drift due to ambient conditions, would make it impossible to exactly place the zero. Also, the plant transfer function is likely to drift, which means that the RH pole could move. So your trying to hit a moving target with a wobbly bow and arrow. A pole and zero very close together is called a 'dipole' and you might do a literature search on that (but beware all the stuff that comes up on dipole antennas!!)

Comment: For reference,see: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa02/caltech/pph02-ch30-31.pdf

Comment: ...or: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vxLVMyFZJgwC&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=zero+cancelling+right+half+plane+pole&source=bl&ots=MXINI-pGSQ&sig=pNIUa_mhCVFNwGEIsSZ9F-fCAyU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AGEgVaWvNIznaLnBguAE&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=zero%20cancelling%20right%20half%20plane%20pole&f=false

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be universally true..

One case where it would be true is if the Plant is actually unstable (due to a pole) & the idea is to cancel it out by including a zero in the controller.  Can you truly cancel out that rogue pole on the right?  no...  you will still have stability concerns

Ideal case (zero exactly on the pole) or practical case (zero just off the pole) still ends up with an unstable system. The only difference is how long it takes for the instability to arise. Never the less a time-dependent stability is still an instability

Consider a plant with a TF:  \$\frac{1}{s^2-1}\$  A second order system. This has poles at +1 and -1

That pole at +1 is a problem,  the right of the origin and thus... unstable.  So why not cancel it out with a zero at +1 from a controller..

Thus a controller would have a TF:   s-1

This produces a closed-loop transfer function of:  \$\frac{s-1}{s^2+s-2}\$

If this was simulated:

```
s = tf('s');
P=1/(s^2-1);
sys = feedback((s-1)*P,1)
step(sys,100)
```

[image]

This wolfrum alpha link also shows it:

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=transfer+function+%28s-1%29%2F%28s%5E2%2Bs-2%29&x=0&y=0

If you extend the time of the **Unit step response plot** you will see its response become undesirable.

--edit--

Take a transfer function \$H = \frac{s-1}{s^2+2s-3}\$

This has a pole at +1 so a 1st thought would be to cancel this pole with a zero at +1 to create:

\$H = \frac{1}{s+3}

Should this system be stable? 1st thought would be yes as it only has one pole. However

The differential equation for this is

\$\ddot{y} + 2\dot{y} - 3y = \dot{u} - u \$

This can further be manipulated to produce:

\$\frac{y_o}{4}(e^{-3t}+e^t)\$

notice that \$e^t\$ term?

http://www.cs.mun.ca/~av/courses/7825-s14/manual_uploads/pole_zero_canc.pdf

Comment: The simulation result you show is not correct, it's just numerical noise of the solver. The unit step response is \$\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 t} \left(e^{2 t}-1\right)\$, which eventually settles at \$\frac{1}{2}\$. There is no instability in the response if the zero coincides exactly with the pole. The practical issue is to achieve that, as pointed out by Chu.

Comment: That is the case here sure but that isn't universally true - see update

Comment: The updated analysis is wrong because you cannot talk about non-zero initial conditions and transfer function analysis in the same breath. The basic assumption in transfer function analysis is zero initial conditions. See wikipedia, Ogata, etc. With the correct analysis (and simulation) you will not see any blow up in the output - only in some internal state.